# Are there any battery-powered Ethernet-to-Wireless adaptors?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wired

Consider the following situation. I have several non-PC devices (e.g. robots & network cameras) and a PC on a wired network. The non-PC devices have an ethernet port and I plug LAN cables between them and the switch.

Normal wireless adapters come as USB sticks which you connect to the PC. So, is there a wireless adapter (battery powered) which I can plug into the **ethernet** port of my non-PC device which connects to a wireless router?

Comment: Are the robots and cameras Industrial devices like Fanuc robots or Cognex cameras?

Comment: @DaveM: Close. We're using JAI cameras.

Comment: Can you explain the application in a bit more detail?  Is the robot battery powered as well?  How long a run time do you need?

Comment: @DaveM: None of the applications are battery powered and are used for several hours. It's OK if the "adapter" needs to connected to a power source.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really enjoy EE classes, but I found an interesting discussion [here](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r19716495-Wireless-adapter-all-USB-No-RJ45) that seems to boil down to this being somewhat unfeasible due to the power draw:

> I looked at a couple of Access Points and 6 watts was about the lowest power that I saw. That was 12 v @ 500 ma. The "big" 9v batteries are 1100 mah, so they would last a little over 2 hours at that drain.

Comment: True, it is technically a wireless bridge "bridging" multiple networks of one device.

Comment: I was disappointed, because I'd have a use or two for this, myself. ;)

Comment: I still think a bridge can be used for this application. Of course, it's quite expensive and most of the bridges I saw online have a minimum of 2 ports when I'd like just one (i.e. one for each device). In any case, it's too expensive.

Answer (score 0):

My associate who is the robotics expert suggests   [Phoenix Contact](http://www.phoenixcontact.ca/)

Answer (score 0):

[Iogear Ethernet-2-WiFiUniversal Wireless Adapter](https://www.amazon.in/Iogear-GWU637-Ethernet-2-WiFiUniversal-Wireless-Adapter/dp/B018YPWORE/)